# AOSP9.0 build failed for SIGILL on hiddenapi

Tags: build, android-source

The environment is :

Win7 x 64 host + Ubuntu14.04 x64 VM on VMWare Workstation 12

source is AOSP 9.0.0_r30

the build error is:

> xargs:
>
> /OpenSource/Build/Android-9.0.0_r30/src-9.0.0_r30/host/linux-x86/bin/hiddenapi:
>
> terminated by signal 4

Answer (score 3):

The right answer is here:
https://github.com/sonyxperiadev/bug_tracker/issues/207

The reason is that my build host CPU(Q6600) doesn't support SSE4 instruction.

The project art require SSE4 because in

```
art\build\Android.bp
```

there are these cflags:

```
        "-msse4.2",
        "-mpopcnt",
```

and the sub project

```
art\tools\hiddenapi
```

inherit these cflags and so the output host executable "hiddenapi" will contain SSE4 instruction and trigger SIGILL during build.

according to the end of this page：https://superuser.com/questions/726395/how-to-check-if-a-binary-requires-sse4-or-avx-on-linux , you can verify this with:

```
objdump -d /OpenSource/Build/Android-9.0.0_r30/src-9.0.0_r30/host/linux-x86/bin/hiddenapi> ~/hiddenapi.asm
```

note:my OUT_DIR_COMMON_BASE is set to

```
/OpenSource/Build/Android-9.0.0_r30/
```

then

```
gawk '/\<(mpsadbw|phminposuw|pmulld|pmuldq|dpps|dppd|blendps|blendpd|blendvps|blendvpd|pblendvb|pblenddw|pminsb|pmaxsb|pminuw|pmaxuw|pminud|pmaxud|pminsd|pmaxsd|roundps|roundss|roundpd|roundsd|insertps|pinsrb|pinsrd|pinsrq|extractps|pextrb|pextrd|pextrw|pextrq|pmovsxbw|pmovzxbw|pmovsxbd|pmovzxbd|pmovsxbq|pmovzxbq|pmovsxwd|pmovzxwd|pmovsxwq|pmovzxwq|pmovsxdq|pmovzxdq|ptest|pcmpeqq|pcmpgtq|packusdw|pcmpestri|pcmpestrm|pcmpistri|pcmpistrm|crc32|popcnt|movntdqa|extrq|insertq|movntsd|movntss|lzcnt)\>/' ~/hiddenapi.asm
```

then you will see that it contains one SSE4 instruction...

After remove the above cflags the source will build successfully.But whether this will produce any bug is unknown now,though since the cflags seems to only affect host executable,the chance is low.

Comment: You can manually make the changes outlined in this commit to add a bypass for this check: https://review.lineageos.org/c/LineageOS/android_art/+/242869

Comment: Facing the same issue when building in VirtualBox + Ubuntu 18.04. The solution worked for me.